# Moq.MockException: Invocation failed with mock behavior Strict

Tags: c#, moq

In the below code, I'm using Moq to test if my Post method is returning CreatedAtRoute StatusCode on successfully addind a book but the test case is failing in Act part when it calls the service and shows the following error:
Moq.MockException: 'IEventRepository.AddEvent(TEMS.Business.Entities.Event) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.'

Test Setup and Tear Down:

```
private Mock<IBookRepository> mockBookRepository;
        public override void TestSetup()
        {
            mockBookRepository = this.CreateAndInjectMock<IBookRepository>();
            Target = new BooksController(mockBookRepository.Object);
        }

        public override void TestTearDown()
        {
            mockBookRepository.VerifyAll();
        }
```

TestCase:

```
        [Fact]
        public void AddBook_ReturnCreatedAtRoute()
        {
            // to prevent autofixture throwing ThrowingRecursionBehavior
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            fixture.Behaviors
                .OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(b => fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));
            fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior(1));

            var books = fixture.Create<Book>();
            this.mockBookRepository.Setup(s => s.AddBook(books)).Returns(1);

            // Act
            BookInputModel booksViewModel = convertDbModelToInputModel(books);
            var actual = Target.Post(booksViewModel);

            // Assert
            var actionResult = Assert.IsType<ObjectResult>(actual);
            Assert.Equal((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, actionResult.StatusCode);
            this.mockBookRepository.Verify(v => v.AddBook(books), Times.Once);
        }
```

Post Method:

```
public ActionResult Post(BookInputModel request)
        {
            try
            {
                Book addBooks = convertDbModelToInputViewModel(request);
                var result = _service.AddBook(addBooks);
                if (result == 0) return BadRequest();
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetBook", new { id = addBooks.Id }, request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Repository:

```
public int AddBook(Book request)
        {
            Book newBook = new Book()
            {
                Name = request.Name,
                Author = request.Author,
                Publication = request.Publication,
                TotalPages = request.TotalPages,
            };
            if (newBook == null) return 0;
            else
            {
                _context.Book.Add(newBook);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return 1;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are invoking members that have no setup configured. I suggest create a setup for all members which are invoked during your tests.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens I think i am not invoking any member that i havent setup. I use AddBooks which i have setup. Rest i am not invoking any member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to realise this little error that was causing the problem - the problem was happening in Act part for the very valid reason as I'm doing setup using DbModel and in Act I'm passing ViewModel(as the Post method in controller requires it) which raises the conflict. Now as far as I'm aware of, the only way to resolve it by using the same model in Post method as of Repository.

Comment: mind accepting your own answer for future visitors?